# What should I type in header file path when header file not found happened?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing on Objective-C , and my app runs on my iPhone 5C. However, it shows "header file not found" when I run archive in Xcode - see the following picture:

[image]

Specifically, it shows `MobileVLCKit/VLCMediaPlayer.h file not found` in `AITPreviewViewController.m` when I run archive, but `MobileVLCKit/VLCMediaPlayer.h` is in the project MobileVLCKit. How do I solve this?

--------------EDIT------------------

And the folder of my project is like the following:

The header file of VLC is in the **importedSources** -> **VLCKit** -> **Headers**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your Project --> Build Settings --> Header Search Paths

Ensure that the search path is the same for all the build configurations.

I think, unlike your debug configuration, the configuration you are using for Archiving (most probably release) has no Header Search Path listed

Edit:
In the Xcode build settings, you have:

- Library Search Paths
- Header Search Paths
- Framework Search Paths

Each of these paths tell your compiler to where to look for in the folder structure for the third party libraries/frameworks/headers you are using.

If you are building it on your own machine (apk) always then its not a problem to have a hardcoded full path the way you have added in the comments.

But, its a good practice to use the $(SRCROOT)/your_path_to_header where $(SRCROOT) will fill in the path up to the project's folder. And its a must have if you are using a different build machine or if a team is working on this project.

In your case, you should type ($SRCROOT)/ImportedSources/VLCKit/‌​Headers when you double click or enter a new search path.

Also, in Xcode, make sure, that the resulting Library/Framework/Header search path is the same as "Full Path" when you right click on that header file and click on "Show File Inspector" (usually you'll see this on the right side)

Comment: I have find the `Header Search Paths` in `Build Settings` . But how do I type for the path of header file ? Is it like `MobileVLCKit/Internal/VLCMediaPlayer.h` ??

Comment: whats the value for your Header Search Paths?

Comment: I set `/Users/apk/Desktop/codetek/temp/qq/WiFiCameraViewer-iOS/ImportedSources/VLCKit/Headers` to `User header search path`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @nitin

In your **Project --> Build Settings --> Header Search Paths**

try add the path of your library path you may try

```
$(SRCROOT)/yourlibpath
```

You can also check for recursive option if above doesn't work.

Since As I can see that the library has been added as project, there must be some `Target Dependency`, or a library to add.

**Goto -> Build Phases**
Click on `Add Target Dependency`
And too `Add Library` in **Link Binary with Library** option

And too I would suggest there must be some **`ReadMe`** for setting up the library, you must be missing something.

**Update**

See some steps to build your library if not [here](https://github.com/rpetrich/MobileVLC/blob/master/HOWTO)

**Update 2**

Also in your `Build Settings` set `YES` to `Always search user paths`, and make sure your `User header paths` are pointing to the Framework.

Comment: Excuse me...I don't understand what the `yourlibpath` mean ? I try the `$(SRCROOT)/MobileVLCKit/Internal`...but it didn't work.

And I could not find any lib in `Target Dependency` and `Add Library`...Can you help me ?

Comment: I guess you don't need to add `Internal`, put upto the root `MobileVLCKit`. And please do check it is exactly pointing the source. `yourlibpath` means what you are trying to do.. But as far I check you need to build libraries from the actual source please check the `HOW-TO` here https://github.com/rpetrich/MobileVLC/blob/master/HOWTO

Comment: I have see the how to. When I open my `WifiCameraViewer` project , it also open the `MobileVLCKit`. It work fine on `IOS device` , but it can not fine header file when I use **`archive`**

You mean I have to build `libraries` from `HOW-TO` and add the libraries to **Build Phases** in `WifiCameraViewer` ?

Comment: I have set YES to Always search user paths. I think my main problem is I don't know what should I type the path of header file. I have add the picture on the above.

I set `/Users/apk/Desktop/codetek/temp/qq/WiFiCameraViewer-iOS/ImportedSources/VLCKit/Headers` to `User header search path`. But it didn't work...

Comment: You can always traverse through path like $(SRCROOT)/../ImportedSources/VLCKit/*.*

Comment: The `$(SRCROOT)/yourlibpath` in my project is under the `WiFiCameraViewer`. But the header file is at MobileVLCKit

Comment: Can you try with setting all the Search Paths? Framework, Header, Library and User.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(SRCROOT)/yourlibpath
```

Just drag and drop the file to your library path.

Comment: The `$(SRCROOT)/yourlibpath` in my project is under the `WiFiCameraViewer`. But the header file is at `MobileVLCKit`

Answer (score 0):

Please check below steps to fix it:

1.Copy the downloaded **MobileVLCKit.framework** file, into your project root folder.

2.Go to your project's target build settings->Header Search Paths add following lines(add the quotes too)

```
"$(PROJECT_DIR)/MobileVLCKit.framework/Headers"
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
```

3.build settings->framework search paths(add the quotes too)

```
"$(SRCROOT)/MobileVLCKit.framework"
"$(PROJECT_DIR)"
```

4.build settings->other linker flags add the following lines

```
-l"bz2" 
-l"iconv" 
-framework 
"MobileVLCKit"
```

5.In General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries add the following library by clicking on the + icon

```
libstdc++.6.tbd
```

6.If you are using `Swift`, most important of all add the reference to the Bridging-Header.h by including the following line

```
#import "MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h"
```

Test by typing `VLCMediaPlayerDelegate`, see if that auto completes. If so help others by pointing them here, else retrace your steps to see what you have missed.

Hope that helps.